# How to view git changes if and only if they are not due to only white characters?

Tags: git

When I want to see what changes were done inside a git commit, I call

```
git show
```

I can add `HEAD` to it with a number of `^`. If I want a specific commit to look at, then I add its hexa. However, there are times when there are a lot of changes, involving a lot of code refactoring using white characters, like enter, space, tab, or an automatic code formatter changes a lot of things.

In this case one might still want to see what the relevant changes were. If there are extremely many such changes, then using `git show` could become cumbersome. My question is as follows: is there a way to see what were the changes in the commit except white-space changes?

If this was the previous code:

```
var dolor = foo ? bar : lorem;
```

and this was the change:

```
var dolor = foo ?
                   bar
                :
                   lorem
;
```

Then we have only white spaces in the change. Is there a way to look at a commit and ignore this kind of change while looking at it? It could literally save many hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to take a look at the documentation of [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show)

> ```
> -b
> --ignore-space-change
> ```
>
> Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at line end, and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace characters to be equivalent.

Or maybe

> ```
> -w
> --ignore-all-space
> ```
>
> Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.

If you combine this option (`-w`) with the `--color-words` option you will get an ever better readable diff output

---

**TLDR**

```
$ git show -w --color-words <commit>
```

Comment: You may also add `--color-words`, which changes the way diff is displayed but ignores whitespace changes as a side effect.

Comment: Very nice answer! I will soon do some experiments to see how it works.

Comment: The solution is git show -w --color-words. AnimiWulpis, if you add this to your answer, I will accept it.